# Compare wav with predefined wav using EXTRA_CONFIDENCE_SCORES - Android

Tags: java, android, wav, voice-recognition

Is there a way to store a wav file somewhere (i.e. a friend's name that wouldn't be understood normally from a voice recognizer, "Geraldo Alkasami") and then compare it to me saying the same phrase into the recognizer using [extra_confidence_scores](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#EXTRA_CONFIDENCE_SCORES)? Would it be user dependent (I would rather it be dependent)?